# How to find source of Too Many Connections exception

Tags: mysql, django

I am getting intermittent "Too Many Connections" exceptions in my Django web-app. Having looked at other Stackoverflow questions regarding "Too many connections", it generally seems like it is an error in coding (ex. spawning a bunch of threads, etc.) that causes many sleeping connections.

I have used `select * from information_schema.processlist order by host;` to check for such connections and I can see maybe 1 or 2 at most but most sleeping connections lifespan are under 10s.

So, I am wondering 2 things:

- Is there a (relatively easy) method for tracking down what in Django may be causing large number of connections?
- If it is really a matter too many people accessing the site at a particular time, what is the standard method to scale the number of connections up?

Comment: It usually means that you aren't closing your connections when you're done with them.  You keep opening new ones until finally you exhaust your allotment.  You need to check your code carefully to make sure that you use connections in the narrowest scope possible and clean them up as soon as you're done.

Comment: Add `unittests` to make sure your code is behaving how you intended.

Comment: Unit tests won't expose issues at scale.

Comment: I am using Django 1.5 and I tried to use the following code based on duffymo's comment and a few answers on other questions. However, it did not seem to close the connection as I expected:


`from django import db
db.close_connection()`


I ran the previously mentioned SQL query while running the script containing this code but I saw the connection continuing to run even after the code should have executed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem: we have a RESTful API and someone was running a periodic script that spawned 700 or so threads to make "reading through the API faster".

However, more important than the cause (which is very specific) is the method for finding it. So I will provide the details in hopes it helps someone else if they encounter a similar situation.

Some further details about my setup:

- In a cloud environment
- Multiple Django web servers behind a loadbalancer

Steps for troubleshooting:

1. Use a monitoring system to alert to alert you if you go over the max connections. Failing that rig a script that polls the MySQL database and uses the following select statement to get info:
   `select substring_index(host, ':', 1), count(*) from information_schema.processlist group by substring_index(host, ':', 1);`
2. From the polling/monitoring check to see if there are any patterns of the system going over at regular intervals. (ex. in my case I saw it go over the max every 5 minutes or so).
3. Check webserver (apache/nginx/etc.) or Django logs to see which URLs/views where being accessed at the time of an overage. (This was harder to determine in my case due to the load balancer causing only a few of the offending URL accesses to happen on each server but based on the time pattern I was eventually able to figure it out).
4. Have a friendly chat with the person causing this grief :)

As for the 2nd part of my original question, because I am in a hosted cloud environment the operators control the max number of connections and often scale it based on the DB instance size. I attempted to upsize once but due to the many threads, the more connections I had the more the process used up.